# Problem with vinyl floor

Tags: vinyl-flooring

My little one dropped a bottle of kerosene and it's all over my vinyl floor in the kitchen. Water is not working to clean it, and I'm scared to use anything else. Any suggestions from expert people? Thanks!

Comment: Why did your little one have access to a bottle of kerosene?

Answer (score 5):

Kerosene is a solvent and, like vinyl, also a hydrocarbon. Their molecular structure causes them to bind together, and if left untreated the kerosene will soften and possibly dissolve the vinyl.

You can use a solution of water and mild soap such as dish detergent to break the bond and soak up the kerosene. Do not flood the floor with the solution. Use small amounts on a sponge or mop - wipe, rinse in a separate container and repeat. Be careful not to scrub the floor as it may scratch easily in its softened state. Evaporate any remaining kerosene by blowing a fan across the spot where it spilled.

Answer (score 0):

Mop most of it up then wash it with soapy water or floor cleaner?